# Renaming a column in a migration script in Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

When I have a [`Table`](http://api.nellafw.org/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Schema.Table.html) reference and I call [`renameColumn()`](http://api.nellafw.org/source-class-Doctrine.DBAL.Schema.Schema.html#237-252) on it, I get the following pair of errors:

> Migration 20130725141653 failed during Execution. Error Table#renameColumn() was removed, because it drops and recreates the column instead. There is no fix available, because a schema diff cannot reliably detect if a column was renamed or one column was created and another one dropped.
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
>
> Table#renameColumn() was removed, because it drops and recreates the column instead. There is no fix available, because a schema diff cannot reliably detect if a column was renamed or one column was created and another one dropped.

(executed via `doctrine migrations:migrate --dry-run`)

Which makes sense... for a diff program.

I'm writing a migration. I know that I want the column renamed (preserving data).
Is there any pure Doctrine method (I don't want to write a raw query) to acheive this?

Answer (score -2):

The 'diff' that the exception is talking about is the diff between your original Schema and your updated Schema. This is how Doctrine generates the SQL statements -- by comparing the current Schema to the modified Schema.

There is no way for Doctrine to reliably figure out that `someColumn` in `$originalTable` is now `someRenamedColumn` in `$modifiedTable` (pardon the bad psuedocode) and so the functionality was removed .

Comment: This is not an answer. It is a restatement of the preamble to the question, and ignores the actual question, which is in the last paragraph. Since I too want an answer to that question (among others) I find this non-answer frustrating. -1.

Comment: Forgive me, the answer is: No, there is no way to use doctrine to rename a column without hand-writing the statement. My previous answer was an explanation, as it was explained to me, at /why/ doctrine disallows this usage-- apologies for being unclear.